How can I add a PerspectiveCamera in RealityView on visionOS using RealityKit?
I want to develop a first person driving VR game. I want to programmatically move the users' view without users moving. I found PerspectiveCamera API in RealityKit. How can I add a PerspectiveCamera in RealityView to simulate driving perspective and disable Vision Pro's default perspectiveCamera?
I have tried to add a PerspectiveCamera, but it was unworkable.
RealityView { content in
    let anchorEntity = AnchorEntity(world: [0, 0, 0])
    let sphereMesh = MeshResource.generateSphere(radius: 1.5)
    let sphereMaterial = SimpleMaterial(color: .white, roughness: 0.5, isMetallic: true)
    let sphereEntity = ModelEntity(mesh: sphereMesh, materials: [sphereMaterial])
    sphereEntity.position = [0, 2, -5]
    anchorEntity.addChild(sphereEntity)

    let camera = PerspectiveCamera()
    camera.position = [1, 4, 0]
    anchorEntity.addChild(camera)
    content.add(anchorEntity)
}


What have you tried so far? The question is too general. What are you specifically having problems with? Thanks.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

You can use a customized PerspectiveCamera on iOS and macOS if a cameraMode property is set to .nonAR (i.e. VR mode). However, visionOS does not yet have its own ".nonAR mode" to activate a customized non-default PerspectiveCamera (even if you run a fully immersive experience).
@available(macOS 10.15, iOS 13.0, *)
@MainActor @preconcurrency 
public class PerspectiveCamera : Entity, HasPerspectiveCamera {

    @MainActor required public init()
}


You can place a PerspectiveCamera object in a visionOS 1.2 app, but it'll have no effect.

Hi. Refer to https://x.com/ShoheOhtani/status/1831267956111868292. Does he use PerspectiveCamera to capture video stream?

Hi Nathan, may the author of this video answer your question?  )))

You can do it now in xCode 16 beta 3. You can do pure swiftUI RealityView with camera.
    @State var camera: PerspectiveCamera =  PerspectiveCamera()
    @State var entity: Entity?
    
    var body: some View {
        RealityView { content in
            content.camera = .virtual
            camera.camera.fieldOfViewInDegrees = 60
            let cameraAnchor = AnchorEntity(world: .zero)
            cameraAnchor.addChild(camera)
            content.add(cameraAnchor)
            if let myEntity = try? await Entity.init(named: "my_entity") {
                entity = myEntity
                content.add(body)
                camera.look(at: patient.position, from: SIMD3<Float>(0,0,1), relativeTo: nil)
            }
        }
        .realityViewCameraControls(.pan) //Set up controls like Scenekit has
        .gesture(SpatialTapGesture().targetedToAnyEntity().onEnded({ value in 

//Do something
}


Why did you make camera and entity "@State" objects? Why not simply "let"?
